# perl: connect in a while loop

Tags: perl, sockets

I read [this](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/connect-intr.html) and I would call connect in a while loop to force connection.
So can I do something like that or is it a stupid idea...

```
sub sendData2Master {
    my ($data) = @_ ;
    my $failed = -1;
    return( $failed ) unless defined $data ;

    my $proto = (getprotobyname('tcp'))[2] ;
    my $sin = sockaddr_in( $PORTMASTER, inet_aton($MASTER) ) ;
    my $FS;
    unless (socket($FS, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)) {
        logger("socket [$MASTER]:[$PORTMASTER] failed:[$?]:[$!]") ;
        return( $failed ) ;
    }

    while (!connect($FS, $sin) && ! $!{EISCONN}) 
    {
        if ($!{EINTR} || $!{EINPROGRESS})
        {
            last;
            # the connection shall be established asynchronously.
            # http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html
        }
        else
        {
            logger("connect to [$MASTER]:[$PORTMASTER] failed:[$?]:[$!]") ;
            if ($!{ECONNREFUSED})
            {
                # tcp server can refuse a connection because a low Listen parameter in IO::Socket::INET->new
                next;
            }
            else
            {
                return ( $failed );
            }
        }

    }

    select((select($FS),$|=1)[0]);
    unless ( print $FS "$data","\n" ) {
        logger("print [$data] to [$MASTER]:[$PORTMASTER] failed:[$?]:[$!]") ;
        return( $failed );
    }
    close ($FS) ;
    select((select(STDOUT),$|=1)[0]);

    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for any advice or sample that already do this...                                                                                    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: This script will just hammer a server who refuses connections, and never give up? Are you sure you don't want to put some time between attempts, and put a maximum on the amount of attempts?